# Handling pdf documents when crawling using scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to parse PDF documents that are encountered while crawling sites using scrapy. I am using the below code to extract HTML page source from PDF document but its not working

```
a = response.xpath("//html").extract()
```

How can I get the content from the PDF documents and incorporate that to scrapy workflow?

Comment: It is not very clear. Can you show the code you have done so far ? So you are using scrapy for reading pdf as html ??

Comment: PDF links? do you mean when you open a PDF file in your browser? that is not a HTML page at all, that's your browser rendering the PDF file and showing its content to you and you can't scrap it's data. you can use Python libs like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfquery to extract data from PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy might not be the best tool to parse pdf documents. But you can identify such links while crawling and add functionality to handle such documents. A solution is to have a parse function to handle such cases and call it when a pdf page is encountered.

As @Morad Edwar has pointed out, you can use libraries like
[pdfquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfquery)
[PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/%7Eeuske/python/pdfminer/) etc.

You can extract data using these libraries and put that data in item pipeline as you normally do with scrapy.

Comment: I can able to extract text data using pdfquery and PDFMiner but how can I extract that PDF page as HTML source.

Comment: extract pdf as HTML? Do you want to use xpaths to extract data?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract PDF as HTML. If done, I can use xpath to to extract data

Comment: In pdfquery and PDFMiner, you can use xpaths.